# Using Composer in Cpanel

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php, cpanel

I am trying to make a Wordpress plugin and I want to continue with composer. As composer is preinstalled in cPanel I haven't installed anything else. My plugin is located at /gg/example/example-plugin.php. But when I type into my Terminal composer init and then my package name(/), I insert (gg/example), but I get as error `The package name )(gg/example) is invalid, it should be lowercase and have a vendor name, a forward slash, and a package name, matching: [a-z0-9_.-]+/[a-z0-9_.-]`
Does anyone know why?

Comment: Did you actually use `gg/example` as your package name?

Comment: @KoalaYeung no, I replaced them with gg and example, but same concept

Comment: I'm afraid we'll need the actual package string to debug your issue. I don't think using `gg/example` would cause this error, but your actual package name might.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I accidently selected the wrong depository.
That was the problem